# Cannot implement dagre-d3.js in Julia Package

Tags: d3.js, julia, dagre-d3

I am coding a Julia Package that implements d3.js and dagre-d3.js to display  Directed Acyclic Graphs. I have a package "D3Graphs.jl" where I print script onto a webpage. I have the following in my julia code:

```
print(io, """<script src=\"https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js\"></script>""")
```

This successfully allows me to utilize d3. However, when I try using the dagre-d3.js (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/master/dist/dagre-d3.js), it does not work. I have the following:

```
print(io, """<script src=\"https://rawgit.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3/master/dist/dagre-d3.js\"></script>""")
```

I have used both rawgit versions as well as cdnjs and even changed the https to http. I also uploaded it to the same folder as my jypter notebook. Is there anything else I could do? Thank you!

Comment: So you're using julia to dynamically create a webpage that uses these javascript libraries, right? What does "does not work" mean? Is the resulting webpage broken? Have you debugged it in your browser? And if it _is_ broken, does the fault lie with your julia output? Or with the logic in the resulting html/javascript code?

Comment: I would echo Tasos -- check what shows up in your browser's debug console.

Comment: Right, I am trying to use julia to dynamically create a webpage. The webpage is broken because when I call dagre-d3, it is not defined. The julia logic is correct, just that dagre-d3 is not defined. All the html/javascript logic also good because I wrote it on a plain html/javascript page on atom and the html page loaded properly on chrome.